# integer manipulation with python

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a integer that looks like this

```
a = 1010101010010100
```

that I would like to turn into something like this

```
list = [[1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0]]
```

What I've tried to do is something like

```
b = str(a)
list1 = [];
for x in b:
    if b.index(x)==0:
        tmp_list = [];
    if b.index(x)!=0%3:
        tmp_list.append(x):
    if b.index(x)==0%3 & b.index(x)!=0:
        list1.append(tmp_list)
        tmp_list=[];
```

I don't get result as expected.

Comment: Do you really mean `a = 1010101010010100`? Not `a = 0b1010101010010100`?

Comment: Is the criteria to just split it by 4 character groups? There are far easier ways to do that.

Comment: Seems like a situation where you would want to use `enumerate` and not `.index(x)` if `x` occurs multiple times.

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `list`, because that is a builtin class name, and you may get odd behavior when you have a variable called list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split your sequence in groups of 4, you can simply do:

```
>>> b='1010101010010100'

>>> [b[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
['1010', '1010', '1001', '0100']
```

or wrap the item in `list(..)` if you need exactly a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(b[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
[['1', '0', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '0', '0']]
```

moreover, if the elements in sublists have to be `int`:

```
>>> [list(int(c) for c in b[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(b), 4)]
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
a = 1010101010010100
k = []
m = [int(i) for i in str(a)]

for j in range(0, len(m), 4):
    k.append(m[j:j+4])
```

output:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of issues in your code -

1. I think you want to do - `b.index(x)%3 == 0` and not `b.index(x)!=0%3` (which does not make much sense, and is always false unless b.index(x) is 0.
2. You have a colon in the line - `tmp_list.append(x):` , this is a syntax error (you should probably remove it).
3. `&` is the bitwise and operator in python, I believe you should be using `and` operator instead of `&` .
4. `list.index(<element>)` gives the first index where the element exists, since your string only consists of 1s and 0s , this would never go past index 2. Instead you should think about using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function , that would provide you the index as well as the value of the element.

A suggestion -

1. You should not have the `if b.index(x)==0:` condition, you can just define the temp_list outside the for loop.
2. Use `if/elif` (instead of all `if`s) .

Example code -

```
b = str(a)
list1 = []
tmp_list = []
for i,x in enumerate(b):
    if i%4!=0 or i==0:
        tmp_list.append(x)
    else:
        list1.append(tmp_list)
        tmp_list=[]
        tmp_list.append(x)
```

output -

```
[['1', '0', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was pretty pseudocode-ish when I wrote it. Since I was writing it out of memory.

Comment: Welcome, do remember to accept answers whichever helped you, it would help the community and anyone who sees the question later.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = str(a)
n = 4
[list([b[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(b),n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of effective solution could be this, from the [itertools receipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

It returns iterator, so it should be pretty fast.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

numbers = str(1010101010010100)
nth = 3
result = grouper(numbers, nth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

a = 1010101010010100
res = []

long = math.ceil(math.log10(a))
digits = [0] * (4 - long % 4) if long % 4 else []
digits.extend([int(i) for i in str(a)])

for i in xrange(0, len(digits), 4):
    res.append(digits[i:i+4])

print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

One of these should do (will provide different results in case your number length % 4 != 0):

```
num = 1010101010010100
[str(num)[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(str(num)), 4)]
[str(num)[i*4:i*4+4] for i in range(0, len(str(num))//4)]
```

Answer (score -2):

List comprehension is your friend (as so many other times):

```
a = 1010101010010100
[list(str(a))[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(str(a)),4)]
```

Comment: Hey thinks. I've done my fair share of list manipulations, but have never seen it used with range with 3 arguments. Thank you!